# Error CS1703 Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported while building the Enterprise Bot Framework project

Tags: c#, nuget, runtime-error, botframework

I got the below error while building the Enterprise Bot Template Project in VS2017. Not sure what i 'm doing wrong here.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
```

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Users\XXX.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll' and 'C:\Users\XXX.nuget\packages\system.runtime.serialization.json\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.    SovereignBot    C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SovereignBot\SovereignBot\CSC    1   Active

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to replicate this issue with a fresh install of the [Enterprise VSIX template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4enterprise). This leads me to believe the issue is either in your code or on your machine.

After researching, it appears there could be a couple of problems and solutions:

**Your Local/Development and Build servers use different versions of Visual Studio**

1. Update Visual Studio for both environments
2. If you're still experiencing issues, try installing the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetcompilerPlatform` NuGet package.

**NuGet or .NET Core is out of date**

1. [Update NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)
2. [Update the appropriate .NET Core SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral). Currently, Bot Framework is supported well on .NET Core 2.2. Keep in mind that if you have 2.2 installed, you may need to update to the latest sub-version (v2.2.104, as of now). Keep in mind you may also need to upgrade your NuGet packages within the project in order to be compatible to the .NET Core SDK.
3. Ensure your bot is using the correct .NET Core Target Framework by right-clicking the Project > Properties > Application:

[image]

**Your Visual Studio version doesn't handle dependency version collisions on its own**

1. Update your Visual Studio

**You have a duplicate reference to the same package (but possibly different versions) in your `.csproj` file**

This is more likely if you're using code brought in from another project.

1. Delete or comment out the duplicate by right-clicking on your Project in Visual Studio, and clicking Edit .csproj:

[image]

**You have a package installed via both NuGet and locally**
(I don't believe this is the issue for you, since both of your packages appear to be in the NuGet directory)

1. Go to the file path of one of the dependencies and delete it.

Comment: Was using the wrong .NET Core Target Framework.. Changed it to 2.2 and all is working properly now. Thanks a lot!